# HSQLDB Trigger - Referencing new table

Tags: sql, triggers, hsqldb

I have following tables (simplified)

```
table A (
    id,
    fingerprint)

table B (
    a_id,
    value)
```

I have following trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER "makeFingerPrint" AFTER INSERT ON "B"
    FOR EACH STATEMENT
       UPDATE "A" SET
           fingerprint = (select sum(value) from "b" where a_id = id)
       WHERE fingerprint IS NULL
```

This works fine for initial insertion and making sure that A's column 'fingerprint' will be NULL.

What I tried to do, is reference new table (all rows) and use theses for update, but I didn't not find way how to reference that newTable.

I tried to find something, but no luck, to reference new table and do

```
CREATE TRIGGER makeFingerPrint AFTER INSERT ON "B"
   REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS newTable   (with and without quotes)
   FOR EACH STATEMENT
   UPDATE "A" SET
           fingerprint = (select sum(value) from "b" where a_id = id)
       WHERE id IN (select a_id from "newTable")
```

I always got error 'user lacks privilege or object not found: newTable'

Any thoughts ? It is even possible to somehow query referencing table ?

Comment: I think your only option is to use a row-level trigger for this.

Comment: My workaround is fine for me, although I will need to watch it (and reset column to NULL if I want to recalculate).

Then, for what cases is there TABLE (referencing new table) ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with triggers written in SQL.

Comment: HSQL extends SQL and I think I read somewhere that it is basically Java class. So I thought that this will be working somehow.